# unsupported DW_FORM values

Tags: c, cmake

Had anybody the same problem as me:
`warning: (x86_64) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 unsupported DW_FORM values: 0x2 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x1e 0x1f 0x21 0x22 0x23 0x24 ...`
I don't know how to solve it. What is it connected with?

I built the project on mac but continue development on Linux. The building was performed with CMake using gcc. When I run the project in the debugger (lldb), I see this warning. Is it serious? I didn't have such a problem on mac. Could this be related with libc?

Comment: What did you do when faced with these errors? Please, add more context about the problem into the question post.

Comment: I built the project on mac but continue development on Linux. The building was performed with CMake using gcc. When I run the project in the debugger (lldb), I see this warning. Is it serious? I didn't have such a problem on mac. Could this be related with libc?

Comment: I don't know. But you definitely need to add information from your comment into the **question post** itself. (Click [edit] button for edit your post).